# Python: Regular expression to match alpha-numeric not working?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match a string that is inputted from a website to check if is alpha-numeric and possibly contains an underscore.
My code:

```
if re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_]',playerName):
            # do stuff
```

For some reason, this matches with crazy chars for example: nIg○▲ ☆ ★ ◇ ◆

I only want regular A-Z and 0-9 and _ matching, is there something i am missing here?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Python has a special sequence `\w` for matching alphanumeric and underscore when the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified. So you can modify your pattern as,

`pattern = '^\w+$'`

Comment: What if LOCALE or UNICODE ARE specified?

Comment: Haven't checked, but it should match alpha numeric characters of specified locale.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Should note that this is a lowercase-w, whereas uppercase-w ("W") is the opposite. https://pynative.com/python-regex-special-sequences-and-character-classes/

Answer (score 49):

Your regex only matches one character. Try this instead:

```
if re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$',playerName):
```

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer to the question when you don't want to get umlaut and other characters as well.

Comment: what does underscore mean here?

Comment: @hampi2017 The underscore has no special properties for regular expressions in Python.

It just lets people register with snake-case names like `george_r_r_martin`.

Answer (score 2):

> …check if is alpha-numeric and possibly contains an underscore.

Do you mean this literally, so that only one underscore is allowed, total?  (Not unreasonable for player names; adjacent underscores in particular can be hard for other players to read.)  Should "a_b_c" not match?

If so:

```
if playerName and re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", playerName):
```

The new first part of the condition checks for an empty value, which simplifies the regex.

This places no restrictions on where the underscore can occur, so all of "_a", "a_", and "_" will match.  If you instead want to prevent both leading and trailing underscores, which is again reasonable for player names, change to:

```
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$", playerName):
// this regex doesn't match an empty string, so that check is unneeded
```