# Python alphanumeric unicode regex not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

Trying to write a python regex that will validate a string comprised of

- Any unicode alphanumeric character (including combining characters)
- Any number of space characters
- Any number of underscores
- Any number of dashes
- Any number of periods

My test strings:

```
9 Melodía.de_la-montaña
9 Melodía.de_la-montaña
```

or as string literals produced with `ascii()`:

```
str1 = '9 Melod\xeda.de_la-monta\xf1a'
str2 = '9 Melodi\u0301a.de_la-montan\u0303a'
```

These look identical but aren't, one is normalized and the other uses the combining characters for the inflections.

Here's my first stab:

```
import re

reg = re.compile("^[\w\.\- ]+$", re.IGNORECASE)
re.search(reg, str1) # None
re.search(reg, str2) # None
```

If I remove the positional qualifiers and use `findall` instead of `search` I get lists like this `['9 Melodi', 'a.de_la-montan', 'a']` or `['9 Melod', 'a.de_la-monta', 'a']`.

I've even tried `re.compile("^[\w\.\- ]+$", re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)` although that should be unnecessary in python 3 right?

In searching for an answer I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039140/python-re-how-do-i-match-an-alpha-character) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923949/matching-only-a-unicode-letter-in-python-re) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722998/python-regular-expression-to-match-alpha-numeric-not-working) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode) but they are all old, deal with python 2, and seem to suggest that the regex I wrote *should* work. The python 3.5 regex docs mention that `\w` should match unicode but offer no actual examples involving non-ASCII text.

How do I match the desired strings?

Comment: Is normalising the string first an option? `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', somestr)? The questions you link to don't apply to your situation, not because they are in Python 2 (the regex engine is the basically same between 2 and 3, except `re.UNICODE` is now the default), but because they are not trying to match combined characters.

Comment: Can you please include the `print(ascii(str1))` and `print(ascii(str2))` versions of the strings too? That way we can trivially copy them without having to worry about using the right encodings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I could, and my first test string *is* normalized, but the regex still isn't matching correctly.

Comment: You probably want to switch to the [`regex` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (slated to be moved into the Python stdlib eventually), as it gives you much more expressive power over what is included and what isn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce the failure for the first case; I get `['9 Melodía.de_la-montaña']`. `\w` matches the Latin-1 codepoints just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters added the url-encoded versions.

Comment: `print(ascii(...))` produces Python string literals, making it *trivial* for us to reproduce. URL-encoded data, not so much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters apologies. I don't know python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sample, `str1`, matches just fine; `\w` includes *all* Unicode word characters, including Latin characters with accents.

You can normalise your strings to the combined form with [`unicodedata.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize), use the `NFC` form:

```
>>> import re
>>> import unicodedata
>>> str1 = '9 Melod\xeda.de_la-monta\xf1a'
>>> str2 = '9 Melodi\u0301a.de_la-montan\u0303a'
>>> reg = re.compile("^[\w\.\- ]+$")
>>> reg.search(str1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 23), match='9 Melodía.de_la-montaña'>
>>> reg.search(str2) is None
True
>>> reg.search(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 23), match='9 Melodía.de_la-montaña'>
```

Note that the `re.IGNORECASE` flag is not needed, `\w` doesn't care about case.