# How to check if a string is strictly contains both letters and numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to check if a string is **strictly** contains both letters and numbers?

Following does not suffice?

```
def containsLettersAndNumber(input):
    if input.isalnum():
        return True
    else:
        return False


isAlnum = containsLettersAndNumber('abc')           # Should return false
isAlnum = containsLettersAndNumber('123')           # Should return false
isAlnum = containsLettersAndNumber('abc123')        # Should return true
isAlnum = containsLettersAndNumber('abc123$#')      # Should return true
```

Please note that It **MUST** contain both letters and numerals

Comment: 'abc' is alphanumeric. you probably want to check 2 conditions at once (has at least 1 number AND has at least 1 letter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Regular expression to match alpha-numeric not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722998/python-regular-expression-to-match-alpha-numeric-not-working)

Comment: yes @user12386945. It MUST have alphabets and numerals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest approach using only string methods:

```
def containsLetterAndNumber(input):
    return input.isalnum() and not input.isalpha() and not input.isdigit()
```

`input.isalnum` returns true iff all characters in S are alphanumeric,
`input.isalpha` returns false if input contains any non-alpha characters, and
`input.isdigit` return false if input contains any non-digit characters

Therefore, if `input` contains any non-alphanumeric characters, the first check is false. If `not input.isalpha()` then we know that `input` contains at least one non-alpha character - which must be a digit because we've checked `input.isalnum()`. Similarly, if `not input.isdigit()` is True then we know that `input` contains at least one non-digit character, which must be an alphabetic character.

Comment: One liner solutions are always attractive!

Comment: Lambda?: `containsLetterAndNumber = lambda input : input.isalnum() and not input.isalpha() and not input.isdigit()`

Answer (score 7):

You can loop through and keep track of if you've found a letter and if you've found a number:

```py
def containsLetterAndNumber(input):
    has_letter = False
    has_number = False
    for x in input:
        if x.isalpha():
            has_letter = True
        elif x.isnumeric():
            has_number = True
        if has_letter and has_number:
            return True
    return False
```

Alternatively, a more pythonic but slower way:

```py
def containsLetterAndNumber(input):
    return any(x.isalpha() for x in input) and any(x.isnumeric() for x in input)
```

Comment: This works. Yep. Thanks for understanding my point here

Answer (score -2):

You can also use regexes bool(re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', 'string'))