# Why does my if statement return the wrong prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, user-input

I am sure the answer is right in front of my face but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the return on my first if statement when I input the right conditions.

```
create_password = input("Enter password here: ")

if len(create_password) > 6 and create_password.isdigit() > 0:
    print("Your account is ready!")
elif len(create_password) < 6 and create_password.isdigit() < 1:
    print("Password must be more than 6 characters and must include a number")
elif len(create_password) > 6 and create_password.isdigit() == 0:
    print("Password must include a number")
else:
    print("Your password sucks")
```

Let's say I enter elephant100, I am trying to get the prompt to be "Your account is ready!". But to my dismay, it prints "Password must include a number" and I cannot figure out why. My other conditions match the right input but that is the only one that does not work.

Comment: What does the isDigit() function look like?

Comment: I don't have isdigit() defined. I thought that I could use the built-in function to check if the password has at least one integer.

Comment: Sorry I came from Java development and I didn't know that was a built in function in python. Personally I would look into Regular Expressions to solve this issue

Comment: You're good, I figured it out using some built in functions that check if the input is only numbers or letters and one that checks if it contains both letters and numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.isdigit()` method returns `True` if all the characters are digits, otherwise `False`. Hence it returns `False` in this case since your string contains letters like e, l, p etc. So the statement `print("Your account is ready!")` will never be executed.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. In that case though, how do I check if a password contains both letters and integers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862663/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-strictly-contains-both-letters-and-numbers

Comment: I did, thanks again. I got an idea on how to fix now

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use isalnum(), isnumeric(), and isalpha() to fix my problem. Thank you Muhammed Jaseem for helping me figure it out! Here is my revised code.

```
if create_password.isnumeric() == True:
    print("Password must be more than 6 characters and include letters")
elif create_password.isalpha() == True:
    print("Password must be more than 6 characters and include numbers")
elif len(create_password) > 6 and create_password.isalnum() == True:
    print("Your account is ready!")
else:
    print("Your password sucks. Must be more than 6 characters and contain only letters and numbers")
```