# why count of record from file is return abnormal

Tags: python

I have file in which their are lot's of records

In that few empty lines are their in middle and even with spaces , tabs as well

**File content :**

```
ABC

GSHJSKK
      
jjj
ajjk
```

So the count should be : `4` but it return `6` from file using below code

**My code:**

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be 4? There's nothing in your code that skips counting empty lines.

Comment: try this `sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt') if line.strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try to read the lines using **regular expressions**. Regular expressions can help you **filtering the lines** with the content you say is relevant.

From what you wrote, I understand that you want to count only the lines containing **alphanumeric strings**, and ignore everything else.

You can filter alphanumeric lines of the files by using this **pattern** `^\w+$` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722998/python-regular-expression-to-match-alpha-numeric-not-working).

Your code could became something like:

```
import re

file = open("myfile.txt", "r")

pattern = r"^\w+$"
line_count = 0

for line in file:                   # for each line in file
    if re.search(pattern, line) :   # if the line read matches the pattern
        line_count += 1

file.close()
```

If you're not so familiar with regular expressions (or you need to verify **how your pattern works**), you can use [this](https://regex101.com/) website, I find it so useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
sum([1 for i in open('myfile.txt',"r").readlines() if i.strip()])
```

Comment: Square brackets are redundant.